# In the SBT shell, why would you set some subproject as active prior to invoking a task there?

Tags: sbt

I have heard from other Scala developers that, when you want to invoke some SBT task limited to a certain `projectID` in the build, it is generally "safer" to *switch* into that subproject first, *then* invoke the task without scope, i.e.:

```
project module1 ; someTask
```

...as opposed to doing what I would think is the most straightforward way: standing in any (=probably the root) project and directly invoking the task for the other project using its *project-scope* prefix:

```
module1/someTask
```

**What** could be the reasons behind this difference? I cannot find anything in the SBT user guide that hints at any difference in behavior. Is there any merit at all behind this advice, or is it simply cargo-cult practice, perhaps meant as work-around for some ancient <0.13 bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's safer in the sense that if you type the following:

```
project module1
someTask
someOtherTask
```

You're still in the subproject for `someOtherTask`: there's no "risk" to run the command in the whole project.

It's likely a matter of personal preferences and habits.